# Git server restored lost 30 days restore commits from local repo

Tags: git

So my companies IT made the huge mistake of deleting all our VMs and on top of that the backup were failing for 30 days. They restored the git server to a 30 old version and I'm trying to figure out how to update the git server history/commits to a co-workers local repo that is only 12 hours old instead. Do anyone now how to do this?

Comment: Replace as lose the history of the repo hosted on the server? I was thinking if it possible to sync the git server to the local repo to preserve all the commits history.

Comment: my guess is that by resetting `origin/...` branches on local to their current places on remote and then pushing all the branches to remote should would. Although what to do with LFS? idk

Comment: What is your problem with this? You should add the remote-repo to the repo of the co-workers repo and then (if the repo is cloned from the original one) basically push it.

Comment: Thank, that seems to be the solution is to just have the co-worker with the local repo push the changes. Just wasn't sure since never encountered this issue.